# Find the area of the region enclosed by the curves in the first quadrant

Tags: calculus, area

Find the area of the region enclosed by the curves $y=3x^2$, $y=8x^2$, $4x+y=4$ in the first quadrant

Do you start by finding the boundaries?

Comment: Are you sure this is the question you want to ask?

Comment: Find the area of the region enclosed by the curves $y=3x^2$, $y=8x^2$, $4x+y=4$ in the first quadrant.

Comment: Have you graphed the equations? Just focus on the graph as it appears in the first quadrant.

Comment: Yes--->http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+y%3D3x2%2C+y%3D8x2%2C+4x%2By%3D4+

Comment: but how do I solve it mathematically

Comment: From the graph, can you identify the region whose area you need to find?

Comment: Is it the first area where they all intersect?

Comment: @BS319 I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A picture is worth 1000 words... So yes start by plotting the relevant functions:

[image]

where $f(x)=3x^2$ is in blue, $g(x)=8x^2$ is in red, and $h(x)=4-4x$ is in green. You want to find the area of the shaded region.

Mouse over the following pieces after you've taken a few minutes to work through the problem yourself:

One:

> Note that $g(x)=h(x)$ when $x=1/2$ and $f(x)=h(x)$ when $x=2/3$.

Two:

> Since $\text{area}=\int_a^b (\text{top}-\text{bottom})\,dx$ and the top/bottom curves are different on $0\le x\le 1/2$ than they are on $1/2\le x\le 2/3$, we split the integral:

Three:

> $\displaystyle\text{area}=\int_0^{1/2} (g(x)-f(x))\,dx+\int_{1/2}^{2/3} (h(x)-f(x))\,dx={5\over 24}+{23\over 216}={17\over 54}.$